# Почему не работает код игры на питоне Анограмы?

Tags: python

```
import random 

print('\t\t\tДобро пожаловать в игру "Анограммы"')
print('\t\tНадо переставить буквы так чтобы получилось осмысленное слово.')
print('(Для выхода нажмите Enter,не вводя своей версии.)')

ws=("питон","Андрей","ответ","простая","сложная","анаграмма","ура")
word=random.choice(ws) 
correct=word

jb=''
while word: 
  pos=random.randrange(len(word))
  jb+=word[pos]
  word=word[:pos]+word[(pos+1):]
  
guss=input('Попробуйте отгодать исходное слово:') 
while guss!=correct and guss!='':
  print('К сажилению вы неправы')
  guss=input('Попробуйте отгодать исходное слово:')
if guss!=correct:
  print('Да именно так!')
  print('Cпасибо за игру') 
  input('\n\nНажмите Enter чтобы выйти')
```

Почему не работает?

Comment: я попробовал отформатировать код, но я не смог угадать. Поэтому, скорее всего и питон тоже не сможет. Плюс, правописание хромает (это мало влияет, но все же)

Comment: @KoVadim Я вроде смог разгадать форматирование. Вот он - минус языка, где пробелы решают всё. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке

```
if guss!=correct:
```

должно быть `==`.
И я надеюсь, что эта строка не под циклом `while`.
А в остальном, вроде работает (если опустить тот факт, что забыли вывести подсказку `jb`).

Comment: не помогло код  запускается но не работает

Comment: @Андрей Что именно не работает? Вот беру ваш код из вопроса (Copy-Paste), меняю один символ как в ответе (Delete-Insert) - и у меня всё работает.

Comment: а всё да действительно всё работает спасибо!